# Make xampp localhost server accessible over internet

Tags: android, networking, xampp, localhost

I am creating an android app which uses xampp server for mainly two purposes, accessing MySql database and making some API calls which I have written in PHP. The app seems to work perfectly fine on the localhost.
But I wish to make my app public over internet. Can someone help me with this?

I have tried changing the httpd-xampp-conf file to grant access to all. I have also enabled port forwarding on my router. But still I am able to access the server only when I am connected to the same IP address as xampp.

Comment: `But I wish to make my app public over internet. ` Dont you mean: `But I wish to make my xampp server public over internet. `?

Comment: `The app seems to work perfectly fine on the localhost.` ?? An Android app on the localhost? What do you mean? Android apps run on Android devices or Android emulators.

Comment: `I have tried changing the httpd-xampp-conf file to grant access to all. I have also enabled port forwarding on my router.` Indeed. That should be done. That should be enough.

Comment: `only when I am connected to the same IP address as xampp.` ??? What do you mean?

Comment: Sorry if the question was not so clear as I am new to Android development and also using xampp for the first time. The problem is that, the app is able to make API calls to the xampp server only if the the Android device is connected to the same network as the xampp server. This might be straightforward, but I want the app to access the xampp server from any network connection.